# MySQL date_add behaviour

Tags: mysql

I've written some SQL to give me a range of dates between two times like so:

```
select date_add(x.min_date, interval ((t500.id-1) * 30) minute) period
from (
    select '2013-08-05T23:00' as min_date, '2013-08-06T01:00' as max_date
) x, 
t500
where date_add(x.min_date, interval ((t500.id-1) * 30) minute) <= x.max_date);
```

Where T500 is a trivial table with column id of 1 to 500 I use for simulating a loop.

Now I expect this to return:

```
2013-08-05 23:00:00
2013-08-05 23:30:00
2013-08-06 00:00:00
2013-08-06 00:30:00
2013-08-06 01:00:00
```

and finish there.  But instead it carries on until 2013-08-06 23:30:00.  I tried different max dates and it always returns dates to the end of the day.  Could someone explain what's happening and how to make it stop when I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing that comes to mind would be casting your date strings into a date format instead of a string for example:

```
cast('2013-08-05T23:00' as smalldatetime)
```